# Sort array from json after fetch

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting, asynchronous

I'm trying to build a little dashboard with VueJS 3.

I have a button which uses the onClick-Listener.

What I want to do onClick is:

Fetch a json from my public directory, parse it, take random elements from an array in the json and then sort them by a certain value

What I'm currently working with:

```js
function load(){
...  
  let json = await fetch("data.json").then((r) => r.json())
  console.log("JSON", json)
  //slice data to be sure, to not just get a reference
  let data = json.data.slice(0);
  console.log("Data", data)
  console.log("Data Type", Object.prototype.toString().call(data))
  console.log("Data Item Type", Object.prototype.toString().call(data[0]))
  console.log("Data Item Property Type", Object.prototype.toString().call(data[0].value))
  let numElements = data.length < 10 ? data.length : 10;
  let elements = [];
  //iterate over data and push random elements to elements array
  for (let i = 0; i < numElements; i++) {
    let randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length);
    let e = data.splice(randomNum, 1)
    console.log("Random Element", e)
    elements.push(e[0]);
  }
  console.log("random Elements", elements);
  //sort elements array
  let sorted = elements.sort((a,b) => {return a.value < b.value ? -1 : a.value > b.value ? 1 : 0;})
  console.log("Sorted", sorted)
...
}
```

Here's the json-file:

```json
{
  "sortDescending": false,
  "type": "Millionen",
  "data": [
    { "name": "@instagram", "value": 383 },
    { "name": "@cristiano", "value": 253 },
    { "name": "@arianagrande", "value": 216 },
    { "name": "@therock", "value": 210 },
    { "name": "@kyliejenner", "value": 208 },
    { "name": "@kimkardashian", "value": 198 },
    { "name": "@selenagomez", "value": 202 },
    { "name": "@leomessi", "value": 176 },
    { "name": "@beyonce", "value": 160 },
    { "name": "@justinbieber", "value": 157 }
  ],
  "left": "Meistgefolgte Instagram Accounts",
  "right": "Laut Socialblade 15.01.2021"
}
```

And the output in the console:

[image: Console Output]

I suspect, that it has something to do with how the asynchronous calls work.

You can see that the JSON is loaded correctly, but directly after that the data variable is of length 0 in the console (although we can iterate over it's length with no problem)

Then when we splice the data and take random elements and push the to a new array, not all of them are added. And the sort doesn't work as well.

I also tried putting the entire block after in another 'then'-chain like:

```js
function load(){
...  
  let json = await fetch("/game_data/data_" + level + "_new.json").then((r) => r.json()).then((json) => {
    let data = json.data.slice(0);
    ...
}
```

But that yielded the same results.

I have also looked at `Promise.all()`, but don't quite understand it and therefore my implementation also yielded no new results.

I'm happy with any help you can provide

Comment: Your mixing a thenable with await, just use await for the `.json()`.   `const f = await fetch(.....);  const data = await f.json()`

Comment: Do I need to put an `await` on every following line then? Also, data is a field in the json, not the json it self. So I tried this with all combinations of `await`s, but it didn't change anything: `const f = await fetch(...); const j = await f.json(); const data = await j.data.splice(0);`

Comment: No, you put await on things that return promises,..   Array.slice, does not return a promise so awaiting this has no effect.   Basically `fetch` returns a promise, and then `.json` returns a promise.

Comment: @Keith, thanks for the clarification. That makes sense. Still though, the console output has not changed at all.